# Displaying Results From Custom Taxonomy Query

Tags: posts, wp-query, query, taxonomy, terms

I have created a custom taxonomy Region and I would like to query this taxonomy for all results and display them. My query is:

```
$args = array(
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'region',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array( 'north', 'east', 'west', 'south' )
    )
)
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

How do I then display this result as html? Something along the lines of this:

```
<li class="location large-3 columns">
   <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/region1.jpg" alt="" />
   <span class="location-title">TAXONOMY TITLE HERE</span>
</li>
```

Comment: You want to list the terms or the posts ?

Comment: The taxonomy terms, now that i think about it it's more like a menu of terms with an image for each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$regions = get_terms('region', array('hide_empty' => false) );
foreach( $regions as $region ){ ?>
<li class="location large-3 columns">
   <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/<?php echo $region->slug; ?>.jpg" alt="" />
   <span class="location-title"><?php echo $region->name; ?></span>
</li><?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing what you need.

Here is how I would probably do it:

```
if($query->posts){
    foreach($query->posts as $post){
        echo '<li class="location large-3 columns">'.PHP_EOL;
        echo '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/region1.jpg" alt="" />'.PHP_EOL;
        $terms = get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'region', '<span class="location-title">', ', ', '</span>');
        if($terms){
            echo $terms.PHP_EOL;
        }
        echo '</li>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

I just prefer retrieving the data, and manually looping/outputting the content.

Otherwise, you could make it more "WordPress friendly" and setup the post data. Look at [this example](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata#Example_1) on the WordPress Codex if you decide to do it that way. You will notice it's very similar to my approach. Either way you can accomplish the same goal. It's just a preference.